# Web3-core-helpers error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Provided address "undefined" is invalid,

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, react, kovan

When I launch the app with with react.. this error occur when my exchange contract is loaded..
Here is the code i wrote to talk to the blockchain:

```
export const loadBalances = async (dispatch, web3, exchange, token, account) => {
  const etherBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(account)
  dispatch(etherBalanceLoaded(etherBalance))

  const tokenBalance = await token.methods.balanceOf(account).call()
  dispatch(tokenBalanceLoaded(tokenBalance))

  const exchangeEtherBalance = await exchange.methods.balanceOf(ETHER_ADDRESS, account).call()
  dispatch(exchangeEtherBalanceLoaded(exchangeEtherBalance))

  const exchangeTokenBalance = await exchange.methods.balanceOf(token.options.address, account).call()
  dispatch(exchangeTokenBalanceLoaded(exchangeTokenBalance))

  dispatch(balancesLoaded())
}
```

web3 `v1.0.0 beta46`
Truffle `v5.0.5 (core: 5.0.5)`
Solidity `v0.5.0 (solc-js)`
Node `v9.10.0`

Here is the error when i use the debugger
[image]

Update: The error i get when i update to web3 v1.2.1
[image]

Comment: Your call stack is incomplete, but it appears to be a problem with loadBalances function and not loadExchange.

Comment: Hi Ismael.. This error occur after the loadExchange function.. This is the only function that suck on the "interaction.js" script.. (i'm using Redux)

Comment: The call stack is incomplete so take what I say with caution but if you look at the bottom there is a loadBalances at interactions.js:130, and everything above it seems related to balances. Without debugging the source code is hard to say anything else.

Comment: Hi Ismael. I saw the loadBalances at interactions.js:130 But now how can i complete the call stack?? Because before that there was not this problem at this level
I do not know why it started to make bugs.. And i'm a beginner in the dApp development..

Comment: You can try to set a breakpoint there and examine the parameters values. Add more debug code around there is no magic you have to debug it like any other webapp.

Comment: Hi Ismael.. Please look at the debug console.. I think the problem came from the HttpProvider..

Comment: What do you think if i update web3 to the new version? I think it's more stable..

Comment: It seems unrelated.

Comment: Do you know a link where this kind of error was reported?

Comment: Please can you take a look to the loadBalance function if it's correct.

Comment: Subscribe is used for events when connecting over websockets so seems unrelated to your callstack. Check if the address used in loadBalances is undefined or anything not an address. Did you try with web3 v1.2.1 it seems you are using an old beta version.

Comment: The loadBalance shows undefined when on the debugger.. I'm using the web3 v1.0.0 beta 46..

Comment: That is a bug reported in web3 https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/3018, so it seems you have to continue using the beta version until it is resolved. If loadBalances shows undefined then you found what is going on, now you have to find why it is being called with undefined.

Comment: Okey.. I'm trying to find why the loadBalances shows undefined and then i'll let you know.. Thank you @Ismael ..

Comment: Hi @Ismael when i debug the code i can see the address of the account are retrieved and when i replace the constant "account" with an address like this 0x2b0A5052fE1D2d8B719F448F4Dd2D96f926D6726 or any other valid address the application run the instance without error but i can't do nothing more..

Comment: I suppose you can search where loadBalances is being called and print before which account is passed. In some place it is being called with undefined. There's console.trace to print the call stack that might help to narrow it down. But it is out of the scope for this forum, better to ask in stackoverflow since it is not related to Ethereum but to javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You declared you function as async but never used the async/await pattern. I added the await at the correct position for you.

Try this:

```
export const loadExchange = async (web3, networkId, dispatch) => {
  try {
    const exchange = await web3.eth.Contract(Exchange.abi, Exchange.networks[networkId].address)
    dispatch(await exchangeLoaded(exchange))
    return exchange
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Contract not deployed to the current network. Please select another network with Metamask.')
    return null
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Niklas the result still the same with the keyword "await"..

Comment: Try adding in the second await as well. (I'm not certain if it works that way)

Comment: Same thing.. I added the second await on the dispatch function..

Comment: Please provide the output of Exchange.networks[networkId].address I think its empty

Comment: You can see the address objet on the screenshot..

Comment: From my perspective Exchange.networks[networkId].address doesn't access the correct value. Can you console.log this seperately please.

Comment: Hi Niklas you can look at the debugger console you can see the breakpoint.. It's about the HttpProvider..